# Getting an error pushing to github - Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote

Tags: git, heroku

I am having a problem pushing to a different heroku remote.

To check myself I renamed my entire project directory to _backup and then:

```
git clone account/repo_name

git remote add repo2 git@heroku.com:repo2.git

git push repo2 branch_abc:master
```

But I am still getting

```
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and merge the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I have tried several SO questions and answers but not worked for me, still getting the error regardless.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**If you don't care about what's currently in repo2 and are confident that totally overwriting it is ok** then you can use:

```
$ git push -f git@heroku.com:<heroku repo name>.git
```

Remember though that `push -f` **can wipe out other developers changes** if they were posted since you last pulled from the repo... so always use with extreme caution on multi-developer teams!
In this case heroku is always downstream and github is where the code is managed and maintained so this makes `push -f` on heroku a safer option that it would otherwise be.

Comment: This will overwrite the remote heroku repo with your local one.

Comment: it do a auto merge on some cases.

Answer (score 7):

I am always a big fan of using git pull --rebase and then git push origin master . A couple of the places I have worked since a lot of places do not allow a push -f (especially places that use bitbucket).

```
git pull --rebase 
git push origin master
```

The rebase will apply your changes after those already to the remote (online website).  This video literally goes over your exact issue and solves it using git pull --rebase https://youtu.be/IhkvMPE9Jxs?t=10m36s

Comment: if I use "git pull --rebase" then my recent local change will be lost, right? but i want to keep recent local change.

Answer (score 6):

If you pull the other repo first:

**git pull repo2**

This will merge in the other repos's changes which you can add and commit.

Then you can push the repo back.

Comment: Yeah, I do that from time to time.  But why does it happen?  Also, the changes always appear to be blank. "Showing zero changed files"

Comment: I suspect it's because repo2 existed before.  Maybe as a skeleton. If so one would either need to pull the skeleton files with `git pull` to have those plus the newer changes merged in.  Then pushing is ok. Or use `git push -f` if confident that the older code is irrelevant.