# failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/myname/myrepo'

Tags: git, emacs, github, magit

question on magit / push

I'm starting using magit, with very little experience in git.

I've gone trough the magit manual with success for :

```
adding
ignoring
staging
commiting locally
```

Then, I try to push on github.com/myname. For that, I use 'P P', entering then my username and password.

If fails with

> To `https://github.com/myname/myrepo` ! [rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)  error: failed to push some refs to `'https://github.com/myname/myrepo'`
>   **hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>
>   hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
>
>   hint: before pushing again.
>
>   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push –help' for details.**
>   git exited abnormally with code 1.

I thought I would solve it as mentionned here with
git config --global push.default current
But it doesn't help.

I've had a lok at [Geting an error pushing to github - Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609263/geting-an-error-pushing-to-github-updates-were-rejected-because-a-pushed-branc) but did'nt got it to work

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you read the hint?

Comment: @SLaks - yes ... thks anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to either `pull` changes first or `push -f` the changes.

Comment: thks ! push -f solved the issue \n it's feasible from within magit

Answer (score 2):

I am always a big fan of using git pull --rebase and then git push origin master since a lot of places where you can work will not allow a push -f.

```
git pull --rebase 
git push origin master
```

The rebase will apply your changes after those already to the remote (online website).  This video literally goes over your exact issue and solves it using git pull --rebase https://youtu.be/IhkvMPE9Jxs?t=10m36s