# Heroku-'up to date', not up to date

Tags: git, heroku

There seem to be many questions like this but I am not finding a solution that works for me.

```
git push heroku master
```

'everything up to date', -not so. Its the same commit that I did yesterday that worked. But today it remains unchanged. I can go to heroku/.../activity and rollback to any version.  But pushing doesnt seem to change anything.  The code at github is correct, but what is heroku looking at?

Any direction appreciated

**Edit**

Things Ive Tried:
-forcing, reseting hard to a commit, pulling then merging first, removing and re-adding my remotes, commiting under a different branch, creating a new heroku app and pushing to that.  All end up showing an old version.

**Update**

I ran

```
git ls-remote heroku
```

and HEAD and refs/head/master both match the most recent commit. But the site still displays an old version.

Note caching is disabled.

**Update**

I ran:

```
heroku git:clone -a (heroku app)
```

to see what was in there, and sure enough the new version is there.  so why when i navigate to it does it render an old version in the browser?

Note there are no name redundancies in the code.

**Update**

Decided to make a new Rails app and copy the files i needed and push to a new heroku app, and maybe just a little bit move on with my life.

Comment: have you try --force?

Comment: are you by any chance working in a none master branch locally?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609263/geting-an-error-pushing-to-github-updates-were-rejected-because-a-pushed-branc/14609377#14609377

Comment: thanks, but no. i dont get it if i git clone the heroku repo to my machine i get the new code but when i navigate to it in the browser i get the old code

Comment: What branch are you on?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was missing a commit of my changes:

```
git commit -am "my comment"
```

before I gave the push command

```
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 1):

If you renamed your app be sure to update the git remote

```
$ git remote rm heroku
$ heroku git:remote -a newname
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps#updating-git-remotes