# error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:<name>/<project>.git'

Tags: linux, git, github

Hi I'm a total newbie using git I read a few StackOverflow Q&A on this error but didn't understand how my problem relates to others with the same error message.  So I didn't dare to chance it and loose 6 hours of work that I need to push to my remote GitHub repo.

.

**1.) The Beginning**

So my code in the local working directory got broken and I couldn't figure out what the problem was.  So I wanted git to go back to the latest working version of my project.  I then found this tutorial and managed to get my local project to go back to a working version.
https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/restore-repo-to-previous-revision

```
$ git reset --hard <SHA-1 HASH NUMBERS>
```

.

**2.) Trying to push**

These are the commands I usually follow when I want to push local code to my remote repo.

```
# Pushing Changes - Staging
$ git diff
$ git status
$ git add -A
$ git status
$ git commit -m "Modified multiply function."

# Pushing Changes - Repository
$ git pull origin master
$ git push origin master
```

.

**3.) The error**

I don't understand what the error message is trying to tell me.  Can somebody help me by showing what sequence of commands I need to run to be able to push code like usual again?

```
penguin@linux$ git push origin master

To git@github.com:<name>/<project>.git

 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward) error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:<name>/<project>.git'

hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote 
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: The remote (which is a separate Git with its own copies of various commits, including its copies of *your* commits) is telling you that if it does what you ask it to do, it will lose some commit(s). These may be your own commits that you already sent to the other Git—it doesn't know or care *whose* commits, only that it would *lose* them—so if you are sure you want to do this, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5816688/1256452.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Geting an error pushing to github - Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609263/geting-an-error-pushing-to-github-updates-were-rejected-because-a-pushed-branc)

Comment: Tnx torek I managed to force away that error with the link you provided.  I also had some detached HEAD issues which I got rid by following Razan Paul's post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228760/fix-a-git-detached-head

But all my changes while in detached HEAD mode was lost after the fixes.  I have copies so I can just recreate them manually I guess.

So in the future when I want to go back to the latest working version on my local working directory.  What procedure will suite my situation best?
I see so many different suggestions I don't know what's best for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's address this rather long comment (which I should do in another comment, but this won't fit *at all* so I'm answering a different question, namely, "how does detaching and reattaching HEAD work"):

> Tnx torek I managed to force away that error with the link you provided. I also had some detached HEAD issues which I got rid by following Razan Paul's post here [Fix a Git detached head?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228760/fix-a-git-detached-head) But all my changes while in detached HEAD mode was lost after the fixes. I have copies so I can just recreate them manually I guess. So in the future when I want to go back to the latest working version on my local working directory. What procedure will suite my situation best? I see so many different suggestions I don't know what's best for me

(incidentally, when addressing a comment to someone in particular you may want to use the `@<name>` syntax so they get alerted).

What you need is a proper Git book.  The best free one is, in my opinion, the [Pro Git 2 book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).  (There are not many, if any, other free ones so "best" could be vacuously true here. :-) )  A shorter, non-*book* reference that I find helpful is [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/), because Git is built atop some very simple bits of graph theory—but unless you know this, and until you realize this, you're stuck in [this xkcd cartoon](https://xkcd.com/1597/).

(I even have [my own start on a book](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf), but I have very little time to work on it these days.)

There are many work-flows you can use in Git.  The first thing to remember, though, is that Git's "unit of storage" as it were—the thing it desperately tries to protect, so that you can get it back—is the *commit*.  That's why you were having trouble pushing: you were telling some other Git: *throw away some commits*.  Git does not want to do that.

Commits are uniquely identified by their hash IDs.  These hash IDs are not very useful to humans, so Git gives us things like branch names to remember particular IDs—but in some cases you may have to resort to raw IDs, which you can cut and paste with your mouse, for instance.

Git's desire to keep commits around means that when you make commits using a detached HEAD, Git tries to keep those too.  It will do so for, by default, at least 30 days.  You can find the hash IDs using `git reflog`.  If you use `git reset --hard` to make Git "forget" commits that were on a branch (rather than a detached HEAD), Git keeps *those* IDs around for at least 30 days as well, on the *branch name*'s reflog.  There's one reflog for each branch name, and one for `HEAD` itself.

Last, an *attached* HEAD—attached being the opposite of detached—is when you are, as `git status` will say, "on" some particular branch:

```
$ git status
On branch master
...
```

In this case, the branch name `master` is how Git actually identifies which commit you have checked out right now; and the name `HEAD` is simply attached to the name `master`.

To make this all work right, **Git works *backwards***.

#### A brief introduction to graphs

To really comprehend what all this means, you need to draw the *commit graph*.  Remember that each commit has its own unique hash ID—those big ugly 40-character-long strings of a hexadecimal number, like `5be1f00a9a701532232f57958efab4be8c959a29`—but that's kind of unweildy, so you might want to just use single letters for small drawings:

```
A <-B <-C   <--master
```

This is a pretty-new repository with just three commits in it.  We made `A` first, then we made `B`, then we made `C`.  (We'll run out of names for commits when we get to our 27th commit, so you can see why Git uses longer hash IDs.)

Since Git works backwards, the name `master` identifies, not commit `A`, but rather commit `C`.  We say that the name `master` *points to* `C`.

Commit `C`, being our third commit, has inside it the name—the hash ID—of our *second* commit, commit `B`.  We say that `C`'s *parent* commit is `B`.  So commit `C` *points to* `B`.  Likewise, `B` has inside it the hash ID of commit `A`, so `B` points back to `A`.

Commit `A` was the first commit.  It *can't* point back to a previous commit, so it just doesn't.  This makes commit `A` special: it's a *root commit*.  Every non-empty repository has at least one of these, the first commit ever made.

When you run `git log`, Git will start with your *current* commit—commit `C`, here—and work backwards: it shows you `C`, and then since `C` points back to `B`, Git shows `B` too.  Since `B` points back to `A`, Git shows `A` as well; but `A` is a root commit, so Git can stop.

#### How branches grow

Since we're on `master`, let's make a new commit `D`.  We'll do whatever we want with the source, `git add` files, and run `git commit` to create `D`.

Where will `D` point back to?  Well, obviously it has to point back to `C`.  So Git makes `D` have a *parent* commit of `C`:

```
A <-B <-C <-D
```

Git's final step here is to change the name `master` so that it holds the hash ID of commit `D`, giving us this picture:

```
A <-B <-C <-D   <--master
```

Note that all the arrows necessarily point *backwards*.  Moreover, all the arrows that are *inside commits* are frozen for all time: `D` points back to `C`, never anywhere else.  The only arrow that *changes* is the one coming out of the branch name!  So I tend to draw them without the internal arrows, to save space and make it fit better:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

This is another key to understanding Git: **branch names move, over time.**  Branches acquire new commits, and the names point to the *last* commit on the branch—what Git calls the *tip commit*.  Git uses this tip commit to find the next-older commit for that branch: the tip's parent.  Git uses *that* commit to find *its* previous commit, and so on, all the way back to the root commit.

#### The name `HEAD` normally just identifies a branch name

Let's complicate-up the above repository by adding a branch coming out of `C`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
       \
        E   <-- develop
```

Here, we now have *two* branches.  The name `develop` identifies commit `E`, whose parent is `C`.  If we now run:

```
git checkout master
```

we'll be `on branch master`, as `git status` will say; if we create a new commit `F` now, its parent will be `D`.  If we instead `git checkout develop` and create a new commit `F`, its parent will be `E` instead.  So Git needs to know: *which branch are we on?*  This is where we need to draw in the name `HEAD`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD)
       \
        E   <-- develop
```

or:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
       \
        E   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

When your `HEAD` is attached like this, it's attached to a *branch name*.  When you make new commits, Git will *change* the branch name so that it points to the new commit you just made.

#### A "detached HEAD" simply holds the commit hash ID directly

If you find yourself in `detached HEAD` mode, it's usually because you checked out an older commit directly.  For instance, let's check out commit `B`, while keeping everything we have:

```
A--B   <-- HEAD
    \
     C--D   <-- master
      \
       E   <-- develop
```

I had to bend the graph lines around to fit `HEAD` in, but now `HEAD` points *directly* to commit `B`.

If we now make a *new* commit `F`, its parent will be `B`, and Git will make `HEAD` point *directly* to `F`:

```
A--B--F   <-- HEAD
    \
     C--D   <-- master
      \
       E   <-- develop
```

Note that whenever Git creates a *new* commit, the commit to which `HEAD` points—directly, if detached, or indirectly, if attached to a branch name—also changes!  The new commit's parent is always whatever *was* `HEAD` just a moment ago, and now `HEAD` is the *new* commit, which is once again the *current* commit.

(This is also why parents don't know their children's hash IDs, but a child does know its own parent's ID.  Git *has* to work backwards, because children know their parents: the parent commits exist when the child is created; but parent commits—which are read-only and frozen in time—don't know what children they will acquire in the future.)

As soon as we re-attach `HEAD`, though, we "lose" the ID of commit F:

```
A--B--F   <-- ???
    \
     C--D   <-- master (HEAD)
      \
       E   <-- develop
```

Who remembers `F`'s ID?  The answer is: *only the reflogs*.

If you want to hang on to commit `F`, you should find its ID in your reflogs and attach a name to it—a branch or tag name, usually:

```
A--B--F   <-- newbranch
    \
     C--D   <-- master (HEAD)
      \
       E   <-- develop
```

Now `newbranch` remembers the ID of `F`.  If you'd made *two* commits, `F` and `G`, while you had a detached HEAD, you'd have to find the *later* one somehow and make sure your name points to `G`, so that you have:

```
        G   <-- newbranch
       /
A--B--F
    \
     C--D   <-- master (HEAD)
      \
       E   <-- develop
```

and not:

```
        G   <-- ???
       /
A--B--F   <-- newbranch
    \
     C--D   <-- master (HEAD)
      \
       E   <-- develop
```

This is why making a lot of commits on a detached HEAD is not a great idea: it can be really hard to tell, from hash IDs, which commit is the *tip-most*.

Comment: Thanks for the many informative golden nuggets!  It's true I'm living the life of that XKCD cartoon. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The git it clearly mentioning that the current branch in which your working is not updated with remote repository as others have committed their code to that repository.

First you need to take a pull of remote repository and then commit your code

> NOTE : Here **origin** is your remote repository location which you
>   might have added

Eg: Considering that your working on master branch

```
git pull origin master  /* To update with the remote repository */

git push origin master /* To push your updated code */
```